# If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is path-connected, with path-connected complement, is $A$ necessarily simply-connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Suppose we're given a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, call it $A$, that satisfies the following.
>
> 1. $A$ is path-connected
> 2. $A^c$ is path-connected
>
> **Q0.** Does it follow that $A$ is simply-connected?

Intuitively, the answer should be "yes"; otherwise, $A$ would have a "hole", and hence $A^c$ wouldn't be connected, and hence *certainly* not path connected. I'm not sure how to transmute this into a genuinely rigorous proof, though.

Note that the converse certainly doesn't hold; for example, $\mathbb{R} \times (-1,1)$ is an open, simply-connected subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ whose complement fails to be path connected.

Some further questions:

> **Q1.** If the answer is "no", does assuming $A$ is open help?
>
> **Q2.** How far can this be generalized? To arbitrary topological spaces, perhaps?

Comment: $n>2$, $A=S^1$.

Comment: @studiosus, nice. That is an answer. Interesting that neither $A$ nor $A^c$ are simply connected in this case. And by swelling $A$ a little bit, it becomes clear that openness doesn't help, either.

Comment: Right. The right thing to look at is called Alexander duality. Once you learn it, it will clarify many things.

Comment: @studiosus, thanks. What is TG?

Comment: A typo, ignore it.

Comment: @studiosus, TG = **t**ypo, i**g**nore.